# Spring session autoconfiguration throws FileNotFoundException: JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration.class not on classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have configured a Springboot application with spring-boot-starter-web. But when I start the application in a Tomcat server it throws the FileNotFoundException.

***pom.xml***

```
    <properties>
        <spring.boot.version>2.0.9.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

***Application.java***

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SessionAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        log.info(context.getApplicationName().toString());
    }

}
```

***Configuration***

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SessionAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ApplicationConfig {
}
```

***application.properties***

```
spring.session.store-type=none
```

***stack-trace***

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/session/jdbc/config/annotation/web/http/JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
```

I don't want to use ***spring-session*** autoconfiguration. I thought I disabled this with the exclude in @SpringBootApplication? Why is spring this looking for this session classes?